# Html anchor horizontally without javascript

Tags: html, css

http://www.indofolio.com/, I'm trying to create a website with similar function to this one, but I don't understand how he did the horizontal scrolling with anchor tag without javascript.
Turn javascript off, and his website is still functionning properly. I really love the progressive enhancement he did.

Test code for horizontal anchoring, take out inline-block and float left and it works perfectly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.ab {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;

}

</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href="#box1">aaaaaaa</a>
 <a href="#box2">bbbbbbb</a>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
    <ul style="width:500%;height:2000px;background-color:red">
        <li class="ab"><a name="box1"></a>
            <div>test</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab"><a name="box2"></a>
            <div>test2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab">
            <a name="box3"></a>
            <div>test3</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab">
            <div></div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab">
            <div></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Quentin said, but his explanation might be a bit lacking if you are new to web design. With javascript off, note that the `url` in changes. The homepage is `www.indofolio.com/#box1` the next has `#box2`, etc. Those are `id`'s of the content boxes that he is using. Normal behavior for an `a` tag is to "jump" to those points if they exist on a page and the anchor is set to do so. His home page anchor is `<a class="link home selected" href="#box1">Home</a>` where the `href` is what causes the jump to that location.

EDIT: Here's some reworked code for your example.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
 <a href="#box1">B1</a>
 <a href="#box2">B2</a>
 <a href="#box3">B3</a>
 <a href="#box4">B4</a>
 <a href="#box5">B5</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="ab" id="box1">
            <div>test1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab" id="box2">
            <div>test2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab" id="box3">
            <div>test3</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab" id="box4">
            <div>test4</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ab" id="box5">
            <div>test5</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.ab {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.ab div {
    height: 500px;   
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
    width: 500%; /* five page widths for five horizontal pages */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}

#container ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#nav a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand how it jumps, but it doesn't work horizontally, I just pasted a code on top just test it. WHen you remove inline-block and float left it works perfectly but not the other way. sadly but it works on indofolio.... its still a mystery

Comment: It's not moving horizontally on indofolio with javascript off. It is just "jumping" into place. The horizontal is only effected with the javascript.

Comment: turn javascript off, turn overflow hidden off on div id="wrapper", the images are align horizontally when you zoom out to minimize the content, and when you click the menu it jumps to it. I know. but it doesn't work normally even on my simple test up there. It wouldn't jump horizontally... nway thanx be more precise plz, cuz Im dumb, and I feel more dumb when I have to precise again.

Comment: Okay, I think I grasp your question now. I edited your sample code. The main key is to make your container wide enough to hold the objects that you are floating.

Answer (score -1):

It scrolls vertically, using regular anchors, if JS is unavailable.

The horizontal positioning is applied with JS.