# Horizontal scrolling without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, progressive-enhancement, graceful-degradation

I'm putting together a horizontally scrolling layout to display nested content (think files within folders within folders *ad infinitum*). For purposes of graceful degradation, is there any way whatsoever to load the page initially scrolled all the way to the right, ***without JavaScript***? It's easy to scroll it all the way to the bottom by adding `<a id="foo"></a>` to the end of the page and appeding `#foo` to the URL, but that doesn't seem to work horizontally.

Comment: Check out this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030074/html-anchor-horizontally-without-javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Check out [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3D4Q4/show/light/#last). You can see that I'm using an anchor to reference an element way on the right of the page (the yellow div), and the browser is scrolling that element into view just as it would scroll downward to bring an element into view that was below the window's edge.

Comment: This looks really good! :) I can't help but wonder if it has to do with the `absolute` positioning and explicit coordinates, though. Would it work if the anchor was e.g. in the rightmost column of a very table that just happened to be really freaking wide?

Comment: You should be able to get it to work no matter what the case. For example, [here it is](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3D4Q4/2/show/light/#last) using floats, and [here's one in a table](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3D4Q4/3/show/light/#last), like you described.